# What does !~ mean in perl

Tags: perl

Can someone explain to me what does this line mean?

```
elsif ($ARGV[0] !~ /^\d+$/
```

The complete code is below, it was meant to echo the input.

```
if (@ARGV != 2) {
    print "Usage: ./echon.pl <number of lines> <string>\n";
    exit;
} elsif ($ARGV[0] !~ /^\d+$/) {
    print "./echon.pl: argument 1 must be a non-negative integer\n";
    exit;
}

$i=0;
while ($i < $ARGV[0]) {#print argv[1] for argv[0] - 1 times
    print "$ARGV[1]\n";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Binding-Operators

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!~` is the negation of the binding operator `=~`, like `!=` is the negation of the operator `==`.

The expression

```
$foo !~ /bar/
```

is equivalent, but more concise, and sometimes more expressive, than the expression

```
!($foo =~ /bar/)
```

Comment: And of course, `=~`  tells the following `m//`, `s///` or `tr///` operator what string to search and possibly transform.

Comment: It's important to remember that m/s/tr are the operators that define behavior, `=~` and `!~` just specify that they should be applied to something other than `$_`. `/foo/` is just `m/foo/`, and if you use `=~` to bind to something that is not one of those operators on the right side, it's stringified and used to match as if with `m//`.